# WP 8.1 Scroll to the top of the ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I would like to automatically scroll to the top of the ListView when the user navigates to this with the back button. I tried to use this:

```
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0.0);
```

It works, but the VS says:

> ScrollToVerticalOffset may be altered or unavailable for releases
>   after Windows 8.1. Instead, use ChangeView.

Okay, I thought it's no problem, I will use ChangeView instead of this. But the ChangeView doesn't work properly. At least in my case. I tried this:

```
scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, 0d, null);
```

It works when I call it for example from a button, but it doesn't do anything when I put it to the OnNavigatedTo method.
So why does it work?

Comment: Have you tried to put it in *OnLoaded* event?

Comment: I put it to the ListView Loaded event and make some condition in the OnNavigatedTo method... and yes, it works perfectly! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look [at MSDN description od *OnNavigatedTo*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto.aspx), you will see that it's called before the visual tree is loaded. Therefore if you want to manipulate your UI elements - do it in [*Loaded*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event:

> You cannot use OnNavigatedTo for element manipulation or state change of controls on the destination page. Instead, attach a Loaded event handler at the root of the newly loaded page's content, and perform any element manipulations, state changes, event wiring and so on in the Loaded event handler.